# How to replace all the text before a word with a blank space using Regex.Replace in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having problems trying to replace a text before a word using C#
I want to delete all the text found before a specific word.
I tried this but it didn't work

```
    string filecomplete = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName));
    string nonimportant = ".*?(?=WORD)";
    string file = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(filecomplete,
    nonimportant, string.Empty);
```

What i want is to keep all the text after the WORD and delete everything before.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure a regex is the right tool for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following option uses the `MatchEvaluator` syntax of Regex.Replace.  Note that you just need to put WORD in place and capture what comes after in a capture group via `()`.

```
string nonimportant = ".*?(WORD.*)";
string st = "aslkfdalksdWORDewot";
string file = Regex.Replace(st, nonimportant, (Match m) => String.Format("{0}",m.Groups[1]));
```

Comment: Realized that you probably wanted to preserve WORD, so I moved it inside the capture group.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Regexp you can use `IndexOf` method in string and `Substring` method like following

```
  var result = content.Substring(content.IndexOf("word"));
```

Moreover because you are reading file into memory for bigger files it will be useful if you read it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

`.` doesn’t match newlines by default – I’m assuming you have some, given the `ReadAllText`. You can pass [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) to change this behaviour.

```
string file = Regex.Replace(filecomplete, nonimportant, string.Empty,
                            RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

(Use `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`.)

Comment: Yes, it has a newline, I added The RegexOptions but it didn't work :S